# Assign value from user profile to collection2 schema

Tags: meteor

How can I assign the values of the meteor profile to a collection2 schema?  I need to assign the email address and name.

I thought it might be something like this but its not:

```
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        defaultValue: function() { return this.user().emails[0].address }
    },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sorted it for the email address:

```
        email: {
          type: String,
          regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
          defaultValue: function(){ return Meteor.user().emails[0].address }
        },
```

For the profile name:

```
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
        defaultValue: function(){ return Meteor.user().profile.name }
    },
```